# Difficulty understanding subgroups for certain simple groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Firstly, I am studying at the high-school level so please excuse my lack of understanding of these concepts.

Consider the group $\Bbb C_{3v}$ of symmetries of an equilateral triangular lamina. It contains the cyclic subgroup $$\Bbb C_{3}=\{\Bbb E,\Bbb C_{3},\bar{\Bbb {C_{3}}}\}$$ because we can take the generator $\Bbb C_{3}$ and raise it to powers to create the other elements of the subgroup.

But what about other groups? Take a group $\Bbb G$ of integers,  $$\Bbb G=\{...,-n,...,-2,-1,0,1,2,...,n,...\}$$

which is an abelian group under addition. I now have difficulty constructing and understanding subgroups for $\Bbb G$. I don't think they can be cyclic, because I can't think of any generators to use to create other elements.

**What would be the subgroups for this example? Would they be cyclic, and how? How does this concept apply to other simple groups?**

Comment: Something has gone wrong with your notation because you have used the same symbol ${\mathbb C}_3$ both for a cyclic subgroup and for an element of that subgroup. Also, when you write "simple group" do you mean something like a group that is easy to understand? You should not do that, because "simple group" has a technical meaning. Also, you seem to have left the important element $0$ out of the group of integers. In fact the subgroups of this group are all cyclic. One of them is the group of even integers, which has the generator $2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt These clarifications are exactly what I'm looking for in an answer, since I'm new to the subject.

Comment: @DerekHolt And wouldn't the group of even *positive* integers have the generator 2?

Comment: The even positive integers do not from a group under addition, because there is no identity element and no inverses. The identity element should be $0$, but even if you included that, then the even positive number $2k$ would have no inverse, which should be $-2k$. They do form a *semigroup* with generator $2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, ah, I was thinking about a group under multiplication.

Comment: @DerekHolt How can the group of even integers have the generator 2? How can a negative even integer be produced using 2?

Comment: Every even integer has the form $2k$ for some $k \in {\mathbb Z}$.